# Cannot enable GD support for ffmpeg-php extension

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, gd

This is from `phpinfo()`

```
ffmpeg

ffmpeg-php version  0.6.0-svn
ffmpeg-php built on Apr 25 2015 20:01:27
ffmpeg-php gd support   disabled
ffmpeg libavcodec version   Lavc52.72.2
ffmpeg libavformat version  Lavf52.64.2
ffmpeg swscaler version SwS0.11.0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
ffmpeg.allow_persistent 0   0
ffmpeg.show_warnings    0   0

gd

GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.11
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.49
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

I just need to enable gd support for ffmpeg. I've tried using `./configure --enable-skip-gd-check` and nothing has worked. I've scoured google for the last 12 hours and tried every "solution" so any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Terminal output after `./configure --enable-skip-gd-check`:

```
root@ip-111-111-111-11 [/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]# ./configure --enable-skip-gd-check
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php
I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for ffmpeg support... yes, shared
checking whether to force gd support in ffmpeg-php... yes
checking for ffmpeg headers... ...found in /usr/include/libavcodec
checking for ffmpeg libavcodec.so... ...found in /usr/lib64
checking for ffmpeg swscale support... yes
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
```

Comment: But what's the relevant `./configure` output? And if you already looked up a lot of suggestions, also link/detail them in your question. Else you'll just get more guessed answers. (Btw, what's the obsession with the ffmpeg extension anyway? Why not just use the plain command line `ffmpeg`?)

Comment: Where can i find this "configure output"? I basically need to take a snapshot of a video that the user uploads and save it as an image. I may have to find a different tool although I'd like to get this working as it suits my purposes and I don't want to quit just because it's inconvenient.

Comment: You said "`I've tried using ./configure --enable-skip-gd-check`". So, what got printed on the terminal?

Comment: The question now includes the terminal output.

Comment: Compiler output. **Relevant** excerpt for once. And installation steps.

Comment: you mean after I do `make` or `make install`?